# Application does't connect to Charles proxy

Tags: certificates, penetration-test, man-in-the-middle, android

I need to check an android app for vulnerabilities. I have to intercept encrypted data sent to the server. This application uses certificate which is placed in res/raw directory, so it is a resource file. I modified it to a [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) proxy root certificate, installed the same certificate on Android, but application does not connect.[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

A common problem with mobile applications and making use of proxy software, such as charles, is that the application may be using "certificate pinning" to prevent proxied interception of the traffic between it and the server.

The easiest way to ascertain this would be to ask the application developer if they're doing that and request a build with that feature disabled to make testing easier (I'm assuming here you're acting as a security reviewer for the app.).

If that's not possible, something like [Android SSL Trustkiller](https://github.com/iSECPartners/Android-SSL-TrustKiller) can be used on a rooted device to remove the certificate pinning and allow interception.